# Calling a function on an array pair

Tags: javascript

```js
function lcmCardinality(n) {
  var factors = []
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      factors.push(i)
    }
  }
  var pairs = [].concat(
    ...factors.map((v, i) => factors.slice(i + 1).map(w => v + ',' + w))
  )
  function gcd(x, y) {
    if (typeof x !== 'number' || typeof y !== 'number') return false
    x = Math.abs(x)
    y = Math.abs(y)
    while (y) {
      var t = y
      y = x % y
      x = t
    }
    return x
  }
  function lcm(a, b) {
    return (a / gcd(a, b)) * b
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= pairs.length; i++) {
    var d = pairs[i]
    var a = []
    a.push(d)
    var z = a.toString().split(',')
    var result = z.map(function(x) {
      return parseInt(x, 10)
    })
    console.log(lcm(...result))
  }
}
```

This is a kata in codewars. I am supposed to get lcm cardinality of a given number (n). The problem is, I am getting one NaN as a result in every test result. To be clear, in the first test, the lcm cardinality of 1 is 1, but I get Nan as a result. In the second example, the given number is 12, the lcm cardinality of that is 8 but I get seven and one Nan and so on..

Comment: Not sure I can follow - the gcd function returns a single value, while the lcm function expects two parameters. How do you want to call lcm with a result from gcd?

Comment: My bad. First, i need the gcd from pairs. Then i will put pairs in lcm function with the found gcd variable.

Comment: You're calling `gcd(a, b)` inside your `lcm` function, so why do you need to get the `gcd` of each element in `pairs` first? Some clarification would be super helpful

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher I ve edited the code with your insight. I am almost there. However, in every test log, I get one NaN, which I do not understand

Comment: This code right here has a smell to it: `if (typeof x !== 'number' || typeof y !== 'number') return false` shouldn't that be returning a number, rather than `false` ? Especially since that returned value is then used as the divisor in a calculation, IF I had to guess, your If statement is failing, it's returning false, which is equating to 0, resulting in a/0 ... which I think would cause a NaN..... hmmm... no, that should result in a divide by zero error... so maybe not... Meanwhile I'd start debugging that sucker and making sure that things are what they are supposed to be.